# $\det({\matrix A - b \cdot\matrix I})$ simplification

Tags: matrices, determinant

I was wondering if there was a way to simplify the formula $\det({\matrix A - b  \cdot \matrix I})$ where $\matrix A$ is a $4\times4$ matrix, $b$ an integer and $\matrix I$ the identity matrix.

Comment: In general, no. If $A$ is of a particular shape (e.g. triangular) yes.

Comment: Thanks, what if A is a symmetric matrix ?

Comment: Do you know the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Consider $\det$ as polinomial of $b$. Then the the coefficient of $b^k$ equals to the sum of main minors of order $n-k$ multiplied by $(-1)^k$. It is dood for your?